# name 'count' is not defined in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code in python and I am trying to make a counter for the iteration of the binary search (yeah I know it is incomplete...), but I am stuck with the variable inside the function, when i try to print the variable count I get this error
name 'count' is not defined in python
can someone explain why i get this error?

```
    import csv
    def binarySearch(arr, l, r, x): 
          
        count=0
        while l <= r: 
        
            mid = int(l + (r - l) / 2) 
                
            # Check if x is present at mid 
            if arr[mid] == x: 
                return mid

            # If x is greater, ignore left half 
            elif arr[mid] < x: 
                l = mid + 1

            # If x is smaller, ignore right half 
            else: 
                r = mid - 1
        # If we reach here, then the element 
        # was not present
        return -1

    with open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        arr=[]

        for row in reader:
            if row ["Publication date (standardised)"] != "":
                arr.append(int(row["Publication date (standardised)"]))  #create list for searching
                list.sort(arr)  #list must be sorted to work
    #print (arr)

    x = 1850  #year to search

    # Function call 
    result = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, x) 
    found = False
    if result != -1: 
        found = True
    print(found)
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you defined count in binarySearch but try to use it outside of the method. Try using a global variable (define it outside of binarySearch), it should work.

Comment: well i need to count the iterations so it needs to be inside the function...I just added to variable count and I have not done the rest of the code, as I got stuck with priting out the "count"

Comment: you can define count as a global variable and you should still be able to use I inside of the function

Comment: when I try i get this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1):

You can return `count` as well.

For example:

```
def myFunc():
    x = 5
    y = 10
    return x,y

a, b = myFunc()

print(a)
print(b)
```

This will be:

```
5
10
```

Note that, I could have written `x, y = myFunc()`. These x and y are not the same as the ones inside myFunc(). The latter are local to the function.

In your code, you can return your local count variable:

```
return mid, count #(A)
return -1, count #(A)
```

And get its value by:

```
result, count = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr)-1, x)  #(B)
```

Again, these two count variables, (A) and (B) are different variables with different scopes.

See, for instance:
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Alternatively, if a global variable, as suggested in the other answer, suits you best, you can see an example of its usage in the link.